# Identification of a subspaces of Rn

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, stochastic-processes

I am working in the field of mechanical engineering. I am interested in stochastic modelling of structures with n random variables. When looking for specific behaviour of the analyzed mechanical system, I found that vectors of the n random variables associated to this behaviour are clustered in a given area of Rn as shown below for `n=3`.

[image]

I am looking for a way to identify or characterize this potential subspace. Quick numerical analyzes underlined that this subspace is not a vectorial space. Indeed, if `a` and `b` are in this space, it is found that `a+b` is not necessarily in it.

I am looking for ideas in order to mathematically characterize this cluster as I do not believe this can be random.

Comment: It looks like a cone to me, something like $z^2 =x^2 +y^2 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear from your diagram, but I'd look at this wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone#Equation_form

As Connor said in the comments, it does look like an eliptic cone.

On the other hand, there are a variety of techniques for characterising data by mathematical means. You could look up *topological data analysis* for information on that.

Comment: thank you for your answer. You are right that the plotted shape is close to an elliptic cone. I will look more into "topological data analysis".

Comment: Feel free to click the check mark if you are satisfied with this answer